# IPv6 only upgrade for IOS app IP address translation

Tags: ios, ipv6

Hi I'm upgrading my old project to support IP6 only requirement from apple. I have these hardcoded dot number IP. How can we transfer it to domain name to meet the new requirement. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

```
//Development
static NSString *const SINGPOST_UAT_BASE_URL = @"https://uatesb1.singpost.com";
static NSString *const CMS_UAT_BASE_URL = @"http://27.109.106.170/mobile2/";
static NSString *const CMS_UAT_BASE_URL_V4 = @"http://27.109.106.170/mobile2/v5/";
static NSString *const AD_UAT_BASE_URL = @"https://uat.mysam.sg/restful-services/advertisementServices/";

//Production
static NSString *const SINGPOST_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL = @"https://prdesb1.singpost.com";
static NSString *const CMS_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL = @"http://mobile.singpost.com/mobile2/";
static NSString *const CMS_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL_V4 = @"http://mobile.singpost.com/mobile2/v5/";
static NSString *const AD_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL = @"https://www.mysam.sg/restful-services/advertisementServices/";
```

Comment: You need to add those ip addresses to a DNS server somewhere and then just use the host names in your app

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Is there any DNS server that we can use?

Comment: Many domain registrars will provide DNS when you register a domain with them

Comment: There is nothing you need to change to "meet the new requirement".

Comment: Hi i thought we have to change those hard cord dot number into domain name?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh: Nope. They would prefer you to, but there is no need.